# Struggling to end loop comparing strings

Tags: c, string, scanf, do-while, strcmp

I am attempting to create a C program that compares a string input with 3 valid strings, if the input isnt the same as any of the strings then it will reloop. Howver I cannot make the loop close even when the user input is valid

```
char HB[3] = "HB";
char FB[3] = "FB";
char BB[3] = "BB";
int x = strcmp(boardType, FB);
int y = strcmp(boardType, BB);
int z = strcmp(boardType, HB);
do {
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Which board type would you like? Full Board(FB), Half Board(HB) or Bed & Breakfast(BB)\n");
    scanf("%s", &boardType);
    printf("%s", boardType);
} while (x != 0 || y != 0 || z != 0);
```

It keeps the loop running even when HB, BB or FB are entered

Answer (score 1):

You never change the values of `x`, `y` and `z` inside the loop, the comparison in never done for new values read from the user.

Also you need to use `&&` instead of `||`, otherwise even if you input the right value for one of the board types the others will be different so the `or` check will loop anyway.

Try to move the `strcmp` inside the loop (I'm assuming that `boardType` is declared somewhere on top and you omitted it for brevity)

```
char HB[3] = "HB";
char FB[3] = "FB";
char BB[3] = "BB";
int x = 1;
int y = 1;
int z = 1;
do {
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Which board type would you like? Full Board(FB), Half Board(HB) or Bed & Breakfast(BB)\n");
    scanf("%s", &boardType);
    printf("%s", boardType);
    x = strcmp(boardType, FB);
    y = strcmp(boardType, BB);
    z = strcmp(boardType, HB);
} while (x != 0 && y != 0 && z != 0);
```

If the comparison is done outside the loop the variables will never change so it doesn't matter what the user inputs, their value always going to be equal to the one they had the first time the loop is run.

Comment: I tried this code but it still loops even when what should be valid inputs have been entered.

Comment: @gil.exe_ have you changed the `||` to `&&`? Using `or` will always result in the loop executing again since one of the three check will always result in `strcmp` being different to 0

Comment: @gil.exe_ this code works fine here. Please show some examples of input and expected vs. actual output.

Comment: @Jabberwocky to be fair I had forgot to change the `||` in `&&` in the code even if I thought about it so copy and pasting it indeed had the same problem before the edit